# How to check upgrade scenario in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, uwp, win-universal-app, upgrade

I have Windows Phone 8 Live on Store and before upgrading to UWP , I want to check upgrade scenario to confirm that everything works ok when the user updates the app. I have a code base for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 10. I tried to run Windows Phone 8 code in Windows 10 v14393 emulator but it gives me an error and due to that I can't check upgrade flow.

Can someone suggest how to check upgrade flow for Windows Apps using Visual Studio and Windows 10 Emulator?

Comment: This document [Move from Windows Phone Silverlight to UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/wpsl-to-uwp-root) might be helpful.